# How to implement a sitemap.xml in index.php, to generate a link with /mysitemap?

Tags: php, heroku, indexing, web, sitemap

I have a folder on my desktop which I suppose is my root folder, where I have a file home.html and an index.php file, with which, with the help of git bash, I have implemented a web page which is working and is hosted in heroku https://alexandrawp.herokuapp.com/. I'm sure my sitemap.xml file has to be placed in the folder of my desktop along with the other two files, my question is what code should I write in my index.php file to get an address like this https://alexandrawp.herokuapp.com/sitemap.xml ?, and be able to view my sitemap.xml and be recognized by google search console
 This is my page: https://alexandrawp.herokuapp.com/, and it should be like this   https://alexandrawp.herokuapp.com/mysitemap

Comment: You need some kind of rewrite rule.

Comment: This isn't something you put in `index.php`.

Answer (score 1):

You should generate your site's sitemap.xml using [the google search console sitemap tool](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/sitemap-list) and place this in the root of your webserver, alternatively if you want to store this in another location under another name you can put this line in your robots.txt

```
Sitemap: http://example.com/sitemap_location.xml
```